# OpenCv on Android without using OpenCv manager is not working

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

am using OpenCv on Android , when I run the application it give me option of installing OpenCv manager , I don't want to use this option for my application. For this I followed [this answer from this forum](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2033/use-opencv-on-android-without-manager/), I follow the steps but still its asking me for OpenCv manager.

Below is my android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
include C:\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := mixed_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and Properties option

[image: ![Project Properties](/upfiles/14265260542819753.png)]

I add below code but it crashes then
  @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }

My code after static initialization

```
public class Tutorial2Activity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    static {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            // Handle initialization error
        }
    }


    private static final String    TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";

    private static final int       VIEW_MODE_RGBA     = 0;
    private static final int       VIEW_MODE_GRAY     = 1;
    private static final int       VIEW_MODE_CANNY    = 2;
    private static final int       VIEW_MODE_FEATURES = 5;

    private int                    mViewMode;
    private Mat                    mRgba;
    private Mat                    mIntermediateMat;
    private Mat                    mGray;

    private MenuItem               mItemPreviewRGBA;
    private MenuItem               mItemPreviewGray;
    private MenuItem               mItemPreviewCanny;
    private MenuItem               mItemPreviewFeatures;

    private CameraBridgeViewBase   mOpenCvCameraView;

    private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                    // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                    System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample");

                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };


    public Tutorial2Activity() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial2_surface_view);

        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial2_activity_surface_view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }
```

and so on

**Edit**

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        final int viewMode = mViewMode;
        switch (viewMode) {
        case VIEW_MODE_GRAY:
            // input frame has gray scale format
            Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame.gray(), mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
            break;
        case VIEW_MODE_RGBA:
            // input frame has RBGA format
            mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
            break;
        case VIEW_MODE_CANNY:
            // input frame has gray scale format
            mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
            Imgproc.Canny(inputFrame.gray(), mIntermediateMat, 80, 100);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
            break;
        case VIEW_MODE_FEATURES:
            // input frame has RGBA format
            mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
            mGray = inputFrame.gray();
            FindFeatures(mGray.getNativeObjAddr(), mRgba.getNativeObjAddr());
            break;
        }

        return mRgba;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: " + item);

        if (item == mItemPreviewRGBA) {
            mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_RGBA;
        } else if (item == mItemPreviewGray) {
            mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_GRAY;
        } else if (item == mItemPreviewCanny) {
            mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_CANNY;
        } else if (item == mItemPreviewFeatures) {
            mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_FEATURES;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public native void FindFeatures(long matAddrGr, long matAddrRgba);
```

Comment: @DavidJhons i update it

Comment: You shouldn't post code using screenshots: just use copy and paste into the answer, then select your code and click on the `{}` symbol to get it formatted as code.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV, you can do **Async** or **Static** initialization. What you want is the static initialization. Remember this is deprecated by the OpenCV to use with production, how you can see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization).

In accordance with the same link, I can see that your `Android.mk` is correct. Apparently what you forgot was the 4th step, that is:

Java initialization code before calling OpenCV API. It can be done, for example, in the static section of the Activity class:

```
static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        // Handle initialization error
    }
}
```

If your application includes other OpenCV-dependent native libraries you should load them after OpenCV initialization:

```
static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        // Handle initialization error
    } else {
        System.loadLibrary("my_jni_lib1");
        System.loadLibrary("my_jni_lib2");
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Don't forget to remove the line that makes the asyn initialization, that is:

```
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);
```

And add this line:

```
mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
```

ps: You edit the `Android.mk` file when your have a project **with a JNI part**. In the case of a project that **doesn’t have a JNI part**, you should just copy the corresponding OpenCV native libs from `OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/` to the `libs/` folder in your project.

**EDIT 2**

To build with the native libs, follow the instrucitions in [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html?highlight=ndk#native-c)

Attemp to the last step:

Either use manual ndk-build invocation or setup Eclipse CDT Builder to build native JNI lib before (re)building the Java part and creating an APK.

That is, you have to run ndk-build in your project root, this way it will be generated the so libs necessary to your app.

Comment: when i add `mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);` it crashes the application , with runtime error. I edit my code

Comment: what do you have in your onCameraFrame method?

Comment: Did you run ndk-build in your project root?

Comment: yes ,it run fine when i install android manager , but i want it to run without android manager

Comment: but from my searchings in SO and from open cv documentation, you have to use manual ndk-build before (re)building the Java part and creating an APK. I will update the answer

Comment: yes i am using CDT Builder and it has generated .so files